# Upper bound Variational Representation of $\chi^2$?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

The $\chi^2$ divergence is an $f$-divergence given by

$$\chi^2(P\parallel Q) = \mathbb{E}_Q\left[\left(\frac{dP}{dQ}-1\right)^2\right].$$

It has a variational representation,
$$\chi^2(P\parallel Q) = \sup_g \frac{(\mathbb{E}_Pg - \mathbb{E}_Qg)^2}{\mathbb{V}_Q(g)},$$
and is closely related the Le Cam metric (and triangular discrimination — they are constant multiples of each other)

$$\mathsf{LC}(P, Q) = \sqrt{\chi^2\left(P \parallel \frac{P+Q}{2}\right)}.$$

In what follows, I will write $M := \frac{P+Q}{2}$, and will specialize to $\chi^2(P\parallel M) = \chi^2(Q\parallel M)$, the square of the Le Cam metric (which is symmetric, and finite).

A related quantity to $\chi^2(P, Q)$ is given by

$$\chi^2_{\mathsf{ind}}(P\parallel Q) = \sup_{g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \{-1,0,1\}} \frac{(\mathbb{E}_Pg - \mathbb{E}_Qg)^2}{\mathbb{V}_Q(g)}.$$

Clearly, $\chi^2_{\mathsf{ind}}(P\parallel Q) \leq \chi^2(P\parallel Q)$.
I am curious to the extent one can reverse this inequality.

> Is there some constant $C_{P,Q}$, perhaps depending on $P, Q$, such that $\chi^2(P\parallel M) \leq C_{P,Q} \chi^2_{\mathsf{ind}}(P\parallel M)$?

As in my setting (with $M = \frac{P+Q}{2}$ the second operand of $\chi^2$) both quantities are finite so the answer is clearly "yes", so properly I need $C_{P, Q}$ to be "small".
I'll describe more what I mean by that shortly.

For certain sub-classes of distributions I can show the existence of $C_{P,Q}$, for example

1. For $P, Q$ discrete random variables on $|\Omega|$, one can take $C_{P,Q} = |\Omega|$, and
2. For $P, Q$ uniform random variables $P, Q$, I believe you can take $C_{P,Q} = 3$.
3. In general when $P, Q$ are distributions on $\Omega$ and  $f(x) := \frac{P(x)-Q(x)}{P(x)+Q(x)}$, then if $\{|f(x)|\mid x\in\Omega\} \subseteq [a,b]$ for $0<a\leq b\leq 1$, you can take $C_{P,Q} = O(1)\log_2(b/a).$

One can check that $f$ is a function that achieves the suprema $\chi^2(P\parallel M)$, i.e. it is natural to consider.

I am mainly interested in bounds of the second form, namely showing that $C_{P,Q}$ is some small function of $P, Q$.
While this is a quite contrived definition, a main application of mine is $P = \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $Q = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\mu\ll \sigma^2$, so any $C_{P, Q}$ that is some small constant in this case will be acceptable.
As the example of Gaussians may show, it is also fine to assume that $P, Q$ have strong concentration properties, i.e. bounded mgfs.

Comment: I changed $\chi^2(P||Q)$ to $\chi^2(P\parallel Q)$ in multiple instances. The latter has spacing proper to a binary relation symbol.